# Android check only desktop is running

Tags: android, android-activity

i'm programing simple SMS manager and my application can view dialog for receive new sms like with GoSMS, now i want to disable it when other application is running and i want to view this dialog when no program is open and launcher is active. i can use this below code to detect it but if user installed any launcher how i can know.

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) G.context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    String currentRunningActivityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
    Log.i(TAG, currentRunningActivityName);
    if (currentRunningActivityName.equals("com.android.launcher2.Launcher")) {
        ///do your task
    }
```

Comment: Desktop? Does it mean launcher apps?

Comment: @Dalinaum yes. that means is launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet, this method can find all launcher and if that return true then desktop's launcher is running by default:

```
public static Boolean isHomeScreen() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) G.context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    String currentActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

    PackageManager pm = G.context.getPackageManager();
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_MONKEY);
    List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(homeIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo temp: appList) {
        if (temp.activityInfo.name.equals(currentActivity))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```